# How to display "Problems" only for the code I changed/added in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-tidy, clangd

After 3 years on VS, I decided to try Visual Code with clangd for a bit.
I work for a big company with huge legacy code and technical debt so I often have to work with some old code and not so modern C++ and more often than not I must read a lot of code rather than write some.

Visual code's code analysis finds hundreds of "Problems" aka warnings fill my entire page which reduces code visibility. Minimap is unusable as 80% is highlighted in yellow.

Is there a way to filter the code analysis so that it only checks and shows warning for the code I just wrote ?

I tried tweaking the user settings of the Code Analysis / clang tidy

Comment: look at the problems and fix the problems that are relevant, most of them are, maybe you fix some bugs in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this currently, but this has been raised in the clangd issue tracker here:

https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/822

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/822#issuecomment-882354673), the conclusion seems to be that such filtering is probably best implemented on the client side, i.e. in VSCode or a VSCode plugin rather than in clangd or clang-tidy.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve it in vscode press F1 then type : clangd: Open project configuration file it should create an empty file for you and then past this inside

```
Diagnostics:
  UnusedIncludes: Strict
  ClangTidy:
    Remove: '*'
```

finally just restart the server to take the changes into account
from F1 -> clangd: restart server

All this only shows the problem I just wrote.

Comment: Note that this will disable all diagnostics in a particular category (those produced by the clang-tidy static analysis tool). If you write new code for which clang-tidy would issue diagnostics, this also suppresses those.